# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 after adding two fields to table

Tags: mysql

I have been working with this database for months. Today I added two fields to the History table `(attend, attend_date)` and my MySQL db fell apart.

Here are the two relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `attendees` (
`attendeeid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`lname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`dojid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`address1` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`address2` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`state` char(2) NOT NULL,
`zipcode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`phonenumber` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`paroleofficer` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`childrest` char(1) NOT NULL,
`groupid` char(2) NOT NULL,
`casedetails` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`disdate` date NOT NULL,
`memberid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`attendeeid`),
UNIQUE KEY `dojid` (`dojid`),
KEY `memberid` (`memberid`),
CONSTRAINT `attendees_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`memberid`) REFERENCES `members` (`memberid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `history` (
`historyid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` float NOT NULL,
`subsidy` char(1) NOT NULL,
`last_payment` date NOT NULL,
`amount_paid` float NOT NULL,
`balance` float NOT NULL,
`attend` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
`attend_date` date NOT NULL,
`attendeeid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`memberid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`historyid`),
 KEY `attendeeid` (`attendeeid`),
 CONSTRAINT `history_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`attendeeid`) REFERENCES `attendees` (`attendeeid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**My insert statement:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO history(amount, subsidy, last_payment, amount_paid, balance, attend, attend_date, attendeeid, memberid)
     VALUES(:amt, :sub, CURDATE(), :amt_paid, :newbal, :attend, CURDATE(), :attid, :memid)');

$stmt->bindParam(':amt', $amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':sub', $subsidy, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$stmt->bindParam(':amt_paid', $payment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':newbal', $newbal, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':attend', $attend, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':attid', $attid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':memid', $memid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

When that statement gets executed, I get:

```
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 
  1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
   a foreign key constraint fails (
    `master`.`history`, CONSTRAINT `history_ibfk_13` FOREIGN KEY 
    (`attendeeid`) REFERENCES `attendees` (`attendeeid`) ON DELETE CASCADE)' 
    in /var/www/html/dfwit/wspostpayments.php:358 Stack trace: 
     #0 /var/www/html/dfwit/wspostpayments.php(358): 
      PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}
```

I have aboslutely no idea why I'm getting this error. I've searched SO and found errors like it, but none that help me untangle my now-broken db. Does anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: show other queries you have before that in example

Answer (score 0):

It means that value for column `attendeeid` on table `history` you are inserting dont exists on table `attendees`. Since u defined such a constraint - it SHOULD

Values of column `attendeeid` on table `history` is dependent on the values of `attendeeid` on table `attendees`

In other words you cannot save a `history` record without adding its `attendeeid` to parent table (`attendees`) first.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: The value of attendeeid that I'm inserting in the History table comes from a Select statement that gathers that information abt the particular Attendee. The History table tracks many attendees. I read the last record for a particular attendee, glean the attendeeid from it ($attid) and use that to insert into the new record for that attendee.

Comment: Forget it. Someone with authority please delete this post. This is embarrassing! After adding the two new fields to the History table, I didn't change the $row[number] for the $attid variable to hold the correct info. Thank you, M0rtis. It was your answer that made me see this. Hope you see this post before it all gets deleted.

Comment: Is working perfectly again. Lesson learned. I thought I had checked everything.